# Part of Speech, Broke-up vs Broke up

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the following sentence, broke-up is an adjective, correct?

> Brad and Jennifer broke-up with their friends

Now if we remove the hyphen, i.e:

> Brad and Jennifer broke up with their friends

what is the parts of speech for 'broke' and 'up' ?

Comment: Verb + preposition. "Broke up" is not a compound word, so a hyphen is not required.

Comment: 'Speech', not 'speach'.

Answer (score 1):

> *Brad and Jennifer broke up with their friends.*

No, it's not an adjective. "Broke" is a verb and "up" is a preposition. Some people call this a phrasal verb, but that term is misleading since it is only "broke" that is a verb.

In your example, “broke up (with their friends)” is a constituent, but it’s not a constituent at word level. "Broke up" is a verb phrase in which it’s just "broke" that is a verb: this is the word that takes verbal inflections.

So we have [1] but not [2]:

[1] *B & J broke up*.

[2] * *B & J break upped*.

Comment: Since  Broke up is a phrasal verb,  then  shouldn't it be Verb + Particle?

Comment: @John I'm saying that the term 'phrasal verb' is inappropriate, for the reason I gave. 'Particle' is not a part of speech, but a general term for prepositions that occur between a verb and its direct object, as in "Kim took **down** the suitcase". Here "down" is a particle, but its POS is preposition and its function is complement.

Comment: Who cares if "particle" is an official POS or not? Everybody uses their own set of syntactic categories, and relatively few would call _up_ in _break up_ a preposition, the way CGEL does. "Verb plus particle" contrasts with "verb plus preposition" for most folks because of particle shift and its constraints.

Comment: @JohnLawler FYI a lot of people care, and what gives you the right to say they shouldn't? You repeatedly seek opportunities to knock CGEL, despite it being an award-winning grammar whose lead author is undoubtedly the finest grammarian of the English language alive today. I disagree with virtually everything you say.

Comment: CGEL is a good grammar; I only question the assertion that its terminology is the standard for all linguistic usage. Because it's not standard. Yet. And there are many many different standards for POS, and nobody has the right, as you point out, to legislate them. Wait 50 years and we can decide what terms linguists are using.

Comment: My point is that OP's and learners in general want answers that they can regard as definitive, and they want them now. CGEL is as close a resource as one is ever likely to find to meet that requirement. Further, they want accurate and crisply-phrased answers. I try to model my answers on that requirement, both here and in my language school. It's no good telling a student that the answer to their question could be x, or it could be y, or it could even be z. That indecisiveness simply won't do.

Answer (score 0):

Break up  is  a phrasal verb. verb plus preposition.It is not an adjective..

so  you need not use the hyphen between the two words.

> **Brad  and Jannifier broke up  with their friendship**

It means that  they stopped their friendship.

I here with  attach a link   to show  how the phrasal  verb  break up  with  can be used.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/break-up

Comment: Actually, they broke up, they broke up with each other, they broke up their friendship, but they did not *break up with their friendship. That's not the idiom. _With_ is used for human participants, but non-human objects are just objects, no preposition.